# Linked List reference in Java

Tags: java, reference, linked-list

If I have a ListNode Class, which is

```
public class ListNode{
  int data;
  ListNode nextNode;
}
```

and a List Class, which is

```
public class List{
  private ListNode firstNode;
  private ListNode lastNode;
  private String name;

public List(String listName){
  name = listName;
  firstNode = lastNode = null; 
  }
}
```

what does the last statement "firstNode = lastNode = null" mean?  Whether firstNode.data = null or firstNode.nextNode = null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: It appears I answered the wrong question. As the OP mentioned in comments below:

> Sorry, my question may not be clear enough, what I am truly confusing is that when executing "firstNode = null", wether firstNode.data = null or firstNode.nextNode = null because firstNode is a object of type ListNode, which has int data and listNode type instances.

After the assignment `firstNode = null`, there is no `.data` or `.nextNode`. You'd have to assign `firstNode` to a `new ListNode()` first.

Once you do that, its `data` member will be initialized to `0` and its `nextNode` member will be initialized to `null`, as those are the default initial values for member fields if no explicit initialization is done. But again, you need to instantiate a `ListNode` and assign it to `firstNode` first, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` if you try and access it while it is `null`.

---

**Original answer, re: `firstNode = lastNode = null`**

It assigns both `firstNode` and `lastNode` to `null`.

It is a commonly used syntactic trick that takes advantage of the fact that an assignment expression as a whole evaluates to the value of the variable after assignment:

```
    a = b = 1   
=>  a = (b = 1)            (b = 1) assigns b then evaluates to 1
=>  a = 1
```

You can chain as many together as you want, as long as the types are compatible:

```
    a = b = c = d = 1
=>  a = b = c = (d = 1)    (d = 1) assigns d then evaluates to 1
=>  a = b = (c = 1)        (c = 1) assigns c then evaluates to 1
=>  a = (b = 1)            (b = 1) assigns b then evaluates to 1
=>  a = 1
```

Incompatible types will result in an error:

```
Integer x;
Double y;
x = y = null; // error: cannot convert from Double to Integer
```

It's the same trick you use when you do stuff like:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = input.read()) != -1) {
   ...
}
```

From [JLS 15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.

Comment: Sorry, my question may not be clear enough, what I am truly confusing is that when executing "firstNode = null", wether firstNode.data = null or firstNode.nextNode = null because firstNode is a object of type ListNode, which has int data and listNode type instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this question does confuse me for a long time. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "starting logic" for an empty `LinkedList` When you instantiate an object of type `List`, it is initially empty, so there is no `firstNode` and no `lastNode`, so they are both `null`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, when executing "firstNode = null", wether firstNode.data = null or firstNode.nextNode = null because firstNode is a object of type ListNode, which has int data and listNode type instances.

Comment: @tony.wang The whole `ListNode` object is null meaning Java doesn't even get to the point of allocating memory for it much less any of its fields.